# How to write a loop to remove all the items in menubar?

Tags: menu-bar, menus

The menubar of the mac port emacs [can not be disabled](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5fnmwo/a_few_questions_about_emacs_macport/dalvltv/).

I currently use

 `(define-key global-map [menu-bar file] nil)
 (define-key global-map [menu-bar edit] nil)
 (define-key global-map [menu-bar options] nil)
 (define-key global-map [menu-bar buffer] nil)
 (define-key global-map [menu-bar tools] nil)
 (define-key global-map [menu-bar help-menu] nil)`

to remove items from the global map.

But I tried to use a loop to do so but failed

`(dolist (menu '(file edit options buffer tools help-menu))
  (define-key global-map [menu-bar menu] nil))`

I just get confused with the variable type of `menu` in `[menubar menu]`. I'm not sure whether it is a symbol or not. So any suggestion on this will be appreciated.

P.S. I'd like to get all the menubar items like from `check-doc-minor-map` rather than just the `global-map`. Can I achieve it? Or if there's some method to add hook to remove all the items before showing the menubar item, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Why not setting `(define-key global-map [menu-bar] nil)`?

Comment: If you really want to iterate you have to use `(vector 'menu-bar menu)` instead of `[menu-bar menu]`. See the doc for Vectors: `A vector, like a string or a number, is considered a constant for
evaluation: the result of evaluating it is the same vector.  This does
not evaluate or even examine the elements of the vector.` So `menu` is not evaluated in your loop code.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for your reply. I've tried that before but setting it to `nil` will cause error when some packages like `helm` or `projectile` or `org` trying to add menu item to default menu like `Tools`. In fact, setting each menu to `nil` still cause this error. I didn't know about vector in emacs-lisp before. Thanks for you information !